# Jtree removeFromParent() creates whitespace

Tags: java, jtree

I am creating a JTree for a project of mine, and the names for some of the nodes dynamically change, and I'm updating the tree using this function:

```
public void updateTree() {
    for (Sprite spr : sprites) {
        spr.getMyNode().removeFromParent();
    }
    treeModel.reload();
}
```

However, when I call this, a row of whitespace shows up like this:

```
Foo
    Child

Foo2
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, I was experimenting and scrolling through the method list of JTree and found tree.updateUI()
and that fixed it.